# как вернуть последнюю строку до пробела

Tags: c#, строки

есть строка

abc [aaa] нужно вернуть [aaa]

Comment: `.Split()[1]`...

Comment: а можно подробнее? спасибо.

Comment: Метод [.Split()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) разбивает текст по указанному значению (будь то текст или символ, при пустом значение разбивает по пробелу.) После этого метода будет массив, где нулевым элементом (в c# отсчет идет с 0) будет `abc`, а первым `[aaa]`, исходя из этого мы можем просто взять по индексу из получившегося массива нужное нам значение.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

```
string phrase = "abc [aaa]";
string[] words = phrase.Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(words[words.Length - 1]);
```

Comment: а если не известно кол-во подстрок в массиве, может быть и aaa bbb [ccc]

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проще использовать регулярные выражения, например:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

internal sealed class Program {
  static void Main() {
    String s1 = "abc [aaa]";
    String s2 = "aaa bbb [ccc] ddd [eee]";

    Regex rex = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\]");
    Console.WriteLine("s1\n{0}\n\ns2", rex.Match(s1).Value);
    rex.Matches(s2).Cast<Match>().ToList().ForEach(
      x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value)
    );
  }
}
```

Итог:

```
s1
[aaa]

s2
[ccc]
[eee]
```